# How to use custom fonts in Xamarin.Android? Typeface issue

Tags: android, xamarin, fonts, typeface

The error says "The name 'Typeface' does not exist in the current context"

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        TextView title = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.title);
        var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "FluoGums.ttf");
        title.Typeface = font;

    }
}
```

Comment: Add a using clause: `using Android.Graphics;` or fully qualify it:`Android.Graphics.Typeface`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

1. create a new fonts directory in the assets directory and put the `FluoGums.ttf` font file here
2. add code in the `onCreate()` method

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

       TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

       AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

       Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, "fonts/FluoGums.ttf");

       title.setTypeface(tf);
   }
   ```